# Can I always drop the T and the D at the end of verbs in the past (or past participle) tense when they come between two consonants sounds?

Tags: past-tense, pronunciation, spoken-english, silent-letter

I am Brazilian and I'm trying to improve my English-speaking skills. I having a tough time linking verbs in the past tense to words starting with consonants other than T and D. I learned that many native English speakers drop the D and T sounds when they come between two consonants sounds.

Here are some examples:

- I talk**ed** with my manager yesterday about a raise.
- The government has express**ed** support for the project.
- His speech has heighten**ed** confusion and discrimination.
- The premiss is based on a prediction prove**d** false.

I don't know if there is a pattern, but I notice**d** some native speakers pronouncing these two letters when they are not speaking fast.

Comment: All of the highlighted consonants are actually pronounced in most dialects of English.  You may be hearing the lack of a /shadow vowel/, which can often happen in slow speech or at the end of sentence.  Also, in AAVE these terminal consonants can be different (glottalized or pronounced as glottal stop) but they are still pronounced there!  (I wish there were an easy way to share audio clips here!)

Comment: And what about Elision? Here's one audio example: https://youtu.be/Y3hMQnIxXVk?t=919. I don't hear him pronouncing the T in "talked with my father"; and the isn't even speaking fast.

Comment: You're right, he doesn't pronounce the "t" sound, but that's probably because he is not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Here's another exemple: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gYYsuGusAE&feature=youtu.be&t=1380. She is a native english speaker.

Comment: Well, I can't hear it. Just one question: Do you pronounce the T in  "went for"?

Comment: Yes and no! When speaking normally, I **don't** pronounce the word "went" in "went for" the same way I pronounce the word "wen" (that's a type of cyst), so my pronunciation **does** reflect the fact that the t is there. However, I do **not** pronounce "went" the same way when saying "I went for it" as when saying "I went." (In the latter case, the tip of my tongue lightly touches the roof of my mouth just behind my front teeth, blocking and then releasing my breath audibly; when I say "went for," that doesn't happen, unless I am deliberately speaking very clearly.)

Comment: Both of the speech clips are in fact "talk" /without/ an -ed.  So, you're hearing them correctly!  The first case is just incorrect use (tenses are different in Polish and Russian and you will often hear mixups like this in speakers more familiar with these languages).  The second, however, is actually correct present tense: "In November, our topic **is**.... we **talk**".

Comment: @BadZen is right, the woman in that clip is using the present tense. (And I guess you removed the second clip, with the male native speaker?)

Comment: Yes, I removed the second clip. I wasn't sure about his background.

Comment: Fair enough. He sounded like a native speaker to me, and I was sure I heard the "t" sound. But then again, I convinced myself I heard it in the clip with the woman speaking until @BadZen correctly pointed out she wasn't using the past tense at all! This sound really can be quite subtle at times, but I think your best bet is **not** to drop it. You may end up sounding like you're over-enunciating just slightly, but you won't be misunderstood. If you drop the sound, people may think you don't know how to use the past tense, and occasionally they may even misunderstand what you're saying.

Comment: I don't know if you have patience to watch this 6 min video, but, If you have, I'd like to know what you think about it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmJdadTCKEI

Comment: Oh, in addition to that glottalization in AAVE - a similar glottalization occurs in 'cockney' British English as well.  Here is a clip of that at work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96j7vD6dt7M  .  Having trouble finding a clear example of the former online easily, surprisingly.  It's similar, however.

Comment: Short answer re: last video - "last time" is true elision.  "it rained the whole time" is a modification, not a n elision.  You could certainly hear a difference if that same speaker were saying "it rain the whole time".  The second would be missing an alveolar stop present in the first that makes the consonant cluster "sharper" or more plosive.  What she is calling "ellision" there is actually that first thing I said above - lack of a small shadow vowel that she places in her "pronouncing each consonant" example.

Comment: **First**, avoid using the words 'always' and 'never' in a question about English. **Second**, Try to enunciate every consonant if you can. **Third**, if you can't enunciate every consonant, you *can* usually drop some consonants like T and D when they come in between two consonants. That's simple elision and most native speakers do it all the time in fast/casual speech. I wouldn't drop the /t/ in your first sentence.

Comment: @Wistful, your comment is the one that makes more sense to me so far. It meets what is said in this lesson from Oxford Online that I found yesterday https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1reZ75Dn8c

Comment: What you learned was wrong or your teachers were clueless. Please see the chart in my answer. I taught English for years and years and I speak fluent Portuguese and know the phenomenon. That of pronouncing walked as walk + a separate syllable ed, rather than with a final t sound. Learn the music first, then you can jazz it up.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, /t/ and /d/ (alveolar stops) decay to [ɾ] (alveolar tap), which may be difficult for you to hear since it’s a less distinct sound and not the one you’re expecting.

As a native speaker, I can still hear the difference between “I talk with” and “I talked with”, or between “burn the toast”, “burned the toast” and “burnt the toast”, etc., but the faster I go, the more subtle it gets. If I slow down to hear it clearly, though, the original /t/ or /d/ comes back.

The best way I can explain it is with the words “tutor” and “Tudor”. These clearly have different sounds if you alternate between them slowly, but as you speed up, they will begin to merge into the same sound as the tongue is forced to move faster.

Comment: @Wistful Thanks for the edit, I’m fairly new to IPA and don’t really understand // vs [] yet.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a basic rule here for English learners**: **ed has three different pronunciations in English based on whether the final consonant is voiced (using the vocal chords) or unvoiced (not using them) or a separate syllable. For example:**

**Here are the rules:**

1. **The /t/ sound**
   **If the last consonant of the word is voiceless, then the ED is pronounced as a T. Be careful not to create an extra syllable or "id" sound.**

**talked (sounds like "talkt")**
kissed (the S sound comes from the front of mouth so it would sound like "kisst")
parked
helped

Voiceless means you do not use your vocal chords in your throat to make the sound, voiced means you do. Voiceless means you push the air out through your teeth for the t sound.

2. **The /d/ sound**
   **If the last letter of the words ends in a voiced consonant (or sound), then the ED is pronounced like a D (without creating another syllable)**

played (sounds like "playd")
closed (the S sounds like a vibrating Z so the word would sound like "clozd")
opened
lived

3. **The /id/ sound**
   If the last letter of the word is spelled with D or T, **the ED is pronounced as a separate syllable with an /id/ sound** (it rhymes with kid and lid).

wanted (sounds like "want-id")
waited
needed
folded

This is all taken from HERE:
[Woodward English which is an excellent site](https://www.grammar.cl/english/pronunciation-ed.htm)

And here is a chart from that site:

[image]

Please note: **in Portuguese, for example, there are no words ending like this** (final t as tapped) or with a final d. Most words end in separate syllable which is why it takes practice to understand this and learn it. Obviously, you have to know the pronunciation of the word in order to know how to pronounce the ED at the end. So, if you learn "talk",that k is voiceless, therefore, talked has a t sound. Likewise, if you learn "learn", you should be able to produce the final d in learned.

Be careful not to say walk-ed with ed as a separate syllable and practice saying: walkt. Many Portuguese speakers do not make that distinction in English, at least when they are beginners.

**If you do not pronounce the final t or d or separate syllable, you will not be using the simple past.** The only way to know that a verb is in the simple past when speaking is to pronounce the final phonemes correctly.

English speakers all make these distinctions and most of them have no idea why. Most don't until they learn how to teach formally teach the language or do some kind of phonology training in linguistics or speech therapy...

The good news here is that this applies to most varieties of English. Tnere is no difference, for example, between BrE, AmE, CanE, AusE,SaE with regard to these pronunciation rules.

[Even in cases like "I talked to my father" in AmE you get: "I talkta my father.""
The final t is very clear though in speech squished together with the pronoun to which becomes an ah sound.]

Comment: I'm sorry for nitpicking every time but  ... what to do...  // *"The only way to know that a verb is in the simple past when speaking is to pronounce the final phonemes correctly."* **/////**  This is not true at all. Pronouncing the *-ed* is not the 'only' way to know that the verb is in past. Context will tell you which form of verb is used. For example, try pronouncing the *-ed* in "I **bathed three** times....".

Comment: Ah.... the reason I nitpick is *I'm concerned about future readers*.... ////// *"Voiceless means you do not use your throat to make the sound, voiced means you do."* ////  We don't use our throat to make voiceless sounds? I assume you meant *"we don't vibrate our vocal folds...."*

Comment: @Wistful In English, when you **speak**, the only way to know the difference between **I bathe every day** and **I bathe*d* every day** is to pronounce that d. Context does not always tell you whether it is simple present or simple past. Have you taught English? Now, one can get into all kinds of weird pronunciation issues but here the OP question merited the response I gave him, which is manifestly was not aware of.

Comment: I agree but the OP is asking about the pronunciation of a consonant when it comes between two other consonants. That's why I chose "bathed three" as an example.

Comment: The one answer that deals with all the simple past issues systematically and you complain about it. Thinking about it: a voiceless t does not use the vocal chords, i.e. the throat. Yeah, cords.

Comment: Vocal cords and throat are not the same. I know it can be confusing but eh... they're completely different.

Comment: **Final – ed is pronounced /t/ after all voiceless sounds. Voiceless sounds are made by
pushing air through your mouth; *no sound comes from your throat*** https://www.ryerson.ca/content/dam/studentlearningsupport/resources/grammar-handouts/Pronunciation_final-ed-es.pdf Yeah, man.

Comment: Please accept my apologies. There's no tap t in 'talkt' but a true t. It's not made in the throat but the air comes out through the throat, so the throat is certainly involved. I'm not picking on you, am I? I only want to correct your erroneous answer so learners find it useful (as it's ELL).

Comment: You need to correct your erroneous comment: "it's not made in the throat but the air comes out through the throat", The air comes out through the TEETH for that t sound.  You have obviously not taught English and you do not want to help because if you did, you would have upvoted my answer as it deals systematically with the pronunciation of simple past.

Comment: First, just because you've taught English, doesn't mean you know how speech sounds are articulated. Where does the air come from? Do teeth produce air??? Second, I would've upvoted your answer if it were not misleading. I upvote any answer I find useful (mostly in the *pronunciation* tag).

Comment: The kind of nitpicking you engage in where I have to come back and argue every little point you chose to misread is really annoying. My answer provides the basic for pronunciation of simple past in English. End of story.

Comment: I'm not arguing. You say you've taught English for years but that doesn't mean you're a phonetician. If you don't know phonetics, don't touch it because it makes your answers misleading. We're all here to learn (except perhaps you). The only thing I'm trying to do is to make your answer flawless because you've spend your precious time on writing out such an in-depth and enlightening answer. Also, it's our right to improve the site. Anyway, I'm sorry for annoying you. Have a nice one!

Comment: I repeat there is nothing about my answer that is misleading. **I am most definitely not here to learn**. I am here to share what I know. You create a tempest in a teacup for no good reason. You do it all the time. You argue minor points that may have been slightly poor expressed. And it is utterly pointless.

Comment: @lambie Thanks for trying to answer my question. But I have to say that you seem to me too much focused on the rule. I already know that rule for the pronunciation of -ed at the end of verbs, but notice that my question isn't specifically about that. In the phrase "I learn**t** something amazing yesterday" the verb doesn't end in -ed. If you are teaching that rule using isolated words as examples, it will work perfectly. But, it doesn't apply to real informal or even formal conversations. It's a fact that many native speakers drop the T and the D when they come between consonants.

Comment: My question is about how much I can do that. I came to the conclusion that I can't do it always, so my task now I to identify when it normally happens. Nowadays I'm putting the tip of my tongue in the position of making the T/D to stop the air flow only, just how how Rachel (from Rachel's English) teaches. I'm getting better doing it, but I really doubt it will become as easy as if I were dropping the letters.

Comment: @RickyR.M. If your question is that simple then the answer is as simple. "No you cannot always drop t and d sounds when expressing past tense, regardless of what you've heard."  You cannot drop the T in learn**t**.  You can't drop the D in metere**d**.  You can't drop the T hope[**t**].

Comment: @EllieK I also came to the conclusion that there isn't a universal truth regarding this issue ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-9xKmuwawg&feature=youtu.be&t=58))

Comment: @Ricky R.M.The verb is **learn**,. it has two forms in the simple past (also past participles): learnt OR learned. That verb in the form learnt (simple past or past participle) is irregular but the t is pronounced like talkt (talked). If you  don't use ed as in learned or t as in learnt, you are not using the simple past. I did not go through every irregular form of all irregular verbs. There are first things first. The dropping of T and D between consonants is not about simple past tense.

Comment: @RickyR.M. See? Another English speaker (the third or fourth now) is telling you the same thing. You are confusing this issue with another one.

Comment: @Lambie I don't follow the majority, but the facts. You're saying to me that the dropping of T and D between consonants is not about the simple past tense when there are abundant evidences showing the opposite. In this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oyV89h1o5U&feature=youtu.be&list=PLrqHrGoMJdTR_P8p95DY1RA8_gD4XEOmI&t=475) we see a detailed explanation of its occurrence in "missed you".

Comment: @RickyR.M.**Todas as frases que você colocou na sua pergunta sâo exemplos das nossas explicaçôes** (talked, expressed, heightened, based). A minha - completa - e as dos outros participantes. Se você nâo pronunciar o t ou d final, nâo é possível estar falando no ou com o passado simples. Senão me acreditar, pode sempre ir à luta,porque eu desisto. Já estou farta.

Answer (score 0):

In casual speech glottalisation of /t/ (its replacement with [ʔ]) - in at least some positions - is far more widespread that AAVE or Cockney (the varieties that have been cited).

For instance, I believe Wikipedia is correct to state that:

> In RP, and in many accents such as Cockney as well as all American English, it is common for /t/ to be completely replaced by a glottal stop before another consonant,as in *not now* [nɒʔnaʊ] and *department* [dɪpɑː(ɹ)ʔmənʔ].
>
>  (Emphasis mine)
>
> [[Glottal replacement]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization#Glottal_replacement)

Secondly, StephenS noted that /t/ and /d/ can change (especially in American English) to an alveolar tap [ɾ].  StephenS observed that /t/ and /d/ are alveolar stops - in English.  The fact that English speakers pronounce /t/ and /d/ against the alveolar ridge, whereas speakers of French and (in many cases) Portuguese are likely to pronounce /t/ and /d/ as dental stops ([t̪] and [d̪] respectively) with the tip of the tongue against the upper teeth instead, may be an underlying factor here.

Comment: (Slanty brackets are for 'phonemes' and square brackets are for 'allophones'. Glottal stop and alveolar tap are not phonemes but allophones of /t/ in English, so I replaced / / with [ ]. Always feel free to roll-back the edit.)

Comment: @Wistful Ah, I knew that, but I wasn't thinking.  I appreciate the corrections.  Thanks.

Comment: @Wistful there isn't dental stops for the T and D in brazilian portuguese. When they don't become other sounds, they are pronounced with the tip of the tongue touching the roof of the mouth behind the upper front teeth, with no air releasement. It is much smoother than the american pronunciation.

Comment: Well, I didn't say it was the case for every accent, but thanks for the information Ricky, and don't blame Wistful for my comments.  It sounds like there are nevertheless interesting differences between the sounds in the two languages (or in the two varieties - Brazilian Portuguese and AmE) - I think you're saying that the Br.Portuguese sounds are unaspirated or much less aspirated than the AmE ones.

Comment: @rjpond If feel no aspiration pronouncing those two letters in my native language. If there is, it's very subtle. It wasn't easy to make the change (unaspirated to aspirated). The pronunciation of the D is much easier, though.

Comment: The examples were talked, expressed, heightened, and based, none of which have anything to do with what you explained. The point is that in Portuguese there is no final T or D sound at all as in expresse/t/, talk/t/, heighene/d/ and base/t/. There are only intervocalic t's and d's in Portuguese in non-initial positions....

Answer (score 0):

No - you shouldn't drop these sounds. If you dropped the *-ed* sounds from the end of "expressed" it would sound like "express", which is the wrong tense and the sentence would sound grammatically incorrect.

Let's look at your first example:

> The government has **expressed support**

You're asking if you can drop the hard sound because it 'comes between two consonants'. By that you must mean the *ss* in "expressed" and the *s* in "support".

Native speakers have no problem pronouncing this. Otherwise we would be unable to say words like *breasts*, *chests* and *nests*. Listening to the way these words are pronounced might help with the transition between the two words in "*expressed support*".

The same goes for your other examples such as "**heightened confusion**". Words don't have to flow into one another, and there are even noticeable breaks in compound words such as "nu**tc**racker" or "fron**tc**ourt".